# Alfresco Share: renaming label on workflow forms

Tags: workflow, label, alfresco

I need to rename some labels on workflow forms. I think I've found the resource bundle that need to be edited. It's slingshot.properties file.

I changed values of workflow.field.message and workflow.field.comment to my preference and restarted Alfresco but nothing's changed. Did I miss something?

Comment: First of all, you SHOULD NOT change any of alfresco's default files. Always override them with yours by placing them in extension folder.

And tell more about which workflow you mean. Do you mean alfresco's default workflows? And in which client? Alfresco explorer or Alfresco Share?

Comment: @MatjazMuhic As in the subject it's in Alfresco Share. Currently I'm working on Adhoc Workflow but the labels appear in all Alfresco's default Workflow. `<field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label-id="workflow.field.message">` is one of label that I want to change.

Comment: Which file are you looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-extension, create a new file called custom-slingshot-application-context.xml with the following content:

   > ```
   > <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   > <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
   > <beans>
   >     <bean id="mycustom.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
   >         <property name="resourceBundles">
   >             <list>
   >                 <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.mycustom</value>
   >             </list>
   >         </property>
   >     </bean>
   > </beans>
   > ```
2. In $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-extension/messages, create a file called mycustom.properties with the following content:

   > ```
   > workflow.field.message=Whatever You Want
   > ```
3. Restart Tomcat

Notes:

- Please use something more descriptive than "mycustom" in both the
  bean ID and the properties file name. This is just an example.
- Create folders where they don't exist already.